# Implementing MVVM without data binding

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

I am currently trying to set up an android project with **MVVM architecture**. Every time I look up about MVVM, all I see is about data binding. Data binding seems like a spaghetti to me. So I have implemented in this way :

```
class MyApplication extends AppCompactActivity{
    errorLD.observe {
        view.doSomethingAbtError();
    }
    mainData.observe {
        updateUI();
    }


}

class MyViewModel extend ViewModel{
    //this is my data        
    data.observe {
        if (data.value.isNull()) {
            errorLD.value = "data is null"
        } else {
            mainData.value = data
        }

    }
}
```

I believe, i can avoid having instances of view in `ViewModel` by using like this.

So the real question is **"Is this implementation can be called as MVVM?"** If not, how can I implement MVVM pattern without data binding?
Thanks for paying attention.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely **MVVM pattern**.

Comment: ok thank u for your confirmation , Jeel Vankhede